# Error on translation workbench

Tags: screen-flow, translation-workbench

I am trying to translate a text on a screen flow. However when I navigate to the flow element on the translation workbench, I get the following error:
Error is in expression '{!reloadEntityAndSetupEntity}' in page TranslationWorkbench.apexp: (System Code).
I am having the error when attempting to translate other screen flows as well.

Anyone familiar with this error?

Comment: This seem to be issue with API version 59, I see bug (W-14363516) is already been logged, will update with more details once I have inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try below workaround(*W-14363516*) which worked for other customers.

When you open for the first time it gives you 2 options Field label and the informational message. When you try with any other component first and then do it in the second occurrence the flow aspect gives the 4 options. 'Field Label, Description, Error Message, Help Text'. When we select the Information Message the error populate.

You will not see the error when four options populate the second time and that can be used for now.

"Information Message" is not a valid option for screen flow and hence it throws error. First try with any other component and then try with flows to avoid the error.